# ember-cli run tests from in-repo addons

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project with some addons created with `ember generate in-repo-addon foo`

When I run `ember serve`, ember-cli serves up my addon assets by combining `/app` and `/lib/foo/app` into `/dist/assets/app.js`.

I expected something similar to happen with tests. When I run `ember test` or browse to `http://localhost:4200/tests`, I only see generated JSHint tests for the main app. Anything I create in `/lib/foo/tests` is ignored.

Where do I create tests for the addon, and how do I run them?

Comment: This Ember CLI RFC is interesting, regarding that matter: https://github.com/ember-cli/rfcs/pull/60

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a feature of Ember-CLI that isn't well documented (good luck finding it) that I used for our in-repo-addon which involves adding a 'test-support' folder to your addon.

In your case you could do something like this in your addon

```
foo
|-- test-support
    |-- helpers
    |   |-- common-helper.js
    |   |-- anther-common-helper.js
    |-- unit
        |-- models
            |-- user-test.js
```

I'm using something very similar with no issues at all. This has save a bunch of time for us, hope this helps

Comment: Wow, so tests in the main project go in the `tests` directory and tests in the addon go in the `test-support` directory. I see now there is documentation about that (searching the docs for "test-support") but it was not obvious at all.

Comment: relavent links:

https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-project-structure

https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-scenarios

Comment: Works correctly, although I feel like `test-support` wasn't meant to be used this way. It's a shame there is no proper way to do that easily

Comment: SeanK message and the guides helped me understand why it is done that way: the addon has its own `tests` (that can be run from its own env), and when the addon wants to extend the tests of the host app, it can use `test-support`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ember generator to create your tests in the addon you'll see where the files get created - it's the same file-structure as in a regular ember-cli project:

```
my-addon
|-- tests
    |-- integration
        |-- my-integration-test
```

You also run the tests for the addon the same way you would for a regular ember-cli project using `ember test` or starting an ember server within your addon's root directory and navigating to `http://localhost:4200/tests`.

The addon creates a dummy app to host your addon for tests.  You can find out more on the official Ember-cli documentation: http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#testing-the-addon-with-qunit